# Vertically aligning text in a table's cell

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I have an event limit link inside a day cell for a full calendar and I'm trying to vertically align it in CSS.

Here is a link to my js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/142/)

It looks like fullcalendar wraps a div around the anchor tag that is the eventLimit link, that ideally would be the best element to vertically align but I don't know if I can access it in CSS. Maybe I can in fullcalendar somehow with eventRender??

Can this be done easily in CSS or is there a better way to do itusing some way in full calendar?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: ''
   },
   //defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
   defaultView: 'basicWeek',
   editable: false,
      height: 174,
      eventLimit: 1,
      eventLimitText: function (numEvents) {
       return numEvents;
      },
   events: [
    {
     title: 'Event',
     start: '2017-09-18'
    },
    {
     title: 'Event',
     start: '2017-09-18'
    }
   ]
  });
  
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your table height to match the height of its container

Try updating your CSS to this:

```
td.fc-more-cell {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.fc-content-skeleton,
table,
tr {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with. check the JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rbynbu4z/1/

I added the below code

```
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton,
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td, 
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton table,
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton tr{
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.fc-row .fc-content-skeleton td div {
      display: inline-block;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use line height for the anchor, it will vertically align the text inside the cell.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jso51pm6/143/) is the fiddle;

```
    td.fc-more-cell {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.3em;
}
td.fc-more-cell a{
  line-height:85px;
}
```